# Dynamic Chart X-Axis labels

Tags: excel, dynamic, charts

I have made a dynamic double bar chart in excel. However, when I add a new label in it pushes another out. It has a list of cities on the x-axis and when I update the city it pushes an old city out and puts the new city in. It seems to only be displaying 20 lables even if I have more than 20. Any ideas on why this is happening?

**Excel: Version 2010**

Comment: What is a "double bar chart"? How do you "add a label"? Share a file. Share  a screenshot. Share more information. Don't let us guess what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Excel will try to fit all labels on a text X axis, but if it gets too tight, it will omit labels. Format the X axis and select "Specify interval unit" set to 1 if you want to show every label on the X axis. If you leave it at "automatic", Excel may omit labels.

[image]

Here is the dialog in 2010.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! There is no Label Position when I right click the chart and hit format axis

Comment: I'm sorry it is contracting work not allowed to give out information or screen shots of the spreadsheet. Sorry for the vaugeness, Excel Version 2010

Comment: Label position is not relevant. It's about "Specify Interval unit". I added a screenshot for 2010.